# How can I generate a signed 32 bit Integer from a UUID and salt string?

Tags: bit-manipulation, uuid

I do not know my bit-twiddling well enough and could use some help.

I'm looking to generate a number to use as a 1-time "communication channel" between 2 different scripted agents to sync up with each other in a system that uses 32 bit unsigned integers as com channels. I need this because it is possible for multiple "sets" of agents to be operating in the same space, and the system delivers messages to all subscribers of a given channel, so it is beneficial to have each pair of synced agents operate on separate channels in order to reduce the number of messages the system server needs to deliver.

The goal is for 2 agents, acting on behalf of a selected user, to independently select the same channel to communicate upon using two pieces of known information; the user's type 4 UUID and a pre-set identifier string. In this way several such pairs of agents can be operating within the same system for several users, with minimal chance of cross-talk.

I came across a function years ago, provided below, and it does produce integer-range numbers.
I provide a pre-set string salt in each "side" of the scripted pair, making them unique from other types of agents in the same space (but identical to one another) and then mix in the UUID of a user for a given pair in order to distinguish pairs of the same setup from one another.

Pseudo-code I have been using to date looks like this:

```
function integer choose_channel(string UUID, string salt){
    string int = (string)((integer)("0x"+subString(UUID,-8,-1)) * Length(salt) * Ceil(Log(Length(salt))));
    return (integer)llGetSubString(setint, 0, 7);
}
```

This function grabs the tail end of the UUID, takes advantage of the use of hex in type 4 UUIDs and casts to an integer. And then alters the result using the length of the salt string. It works, but it also means that the salt string is mostly meaningless--the length is all that matters. Salts of "abcde" and "*F1@w" would produce the same result for the same user.

Is there a way that I can use the salt string (UTF16 be default, but I can convert if needed) to change my resulting integer in a way that uses the uniqueness of characters in the salt string, but produces safe 32-bit signed integers?

Comment: What about simply hashing the UUID together with the salt, using your favorite hash function, and then take the first/last 4 bytes of the result?  It doesn't guarantee that inputs with different salt won't collide, but there's a low probability.  Anyway, it is mathematically impossible to avoid all possibility of collision if the salt and the output are the same size, unless you use *only* the salt for the output and ignore the UUID altogether.

Comment: Hmm, that might do it... I will experiment. I worry it sort of slides the question into another one--"is there a string hash function that evenly distributes the first/last four bytes" which might be a very difficult one to work out. Avoiding collisions isn't essential, thankfully (once a channel is established, additional exchanges occur); reducing them as much as possible is the main desire so this is a "could be enough for my needs."

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism seems to work for me, inspired by Nate Eldredge's suggestion to hash them together.

Pseudo:

```
integer number_based_on_ID(string UUID, string salt)
{
    string hash = Copy_String( HMAC( UUID, salt) ,0,3); // Copy 4 characters
    bytes = [  ((dword = (( Base64Encode(Copy_String(hash, 0, 3) + "==") >>  8) & 0xFFFFF)) >> 16), ((dword >> 8) & 0xFF), (dword & 0xFF) ];
    return (integer)( "0x"+(string)bytes );
}
```

Running in 1000 number batches typically returns 2-4 collisions, which seems to be working well enough.